# XSD - Allow one specific element multiple times while allowing others just one time

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I'm trying to create a `complexType` in which I'm able to write he following:

```
<MyType>
    <tag1>Something</tag1>
    <tag2>Tag 1</tag2>
    <tag2>Tag 2</tag2>
    <tag3>Another something</tag3>
</MyTpe>
```

Basically I want to be able to specify the tags in no particular order but be able to specify `tag2` unlimited times. How can I do this?

I already tried a `choice`, but it seems that it would allow any element unlimited times.

Here is the relevant part of my XSD:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyType">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="tag1" />
        <xsd:element name="tag3" />
    </xsd:all>
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="tag2"  />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```